# If I have a list of split arguments seperated by spaces, how would I join the ones within qoutes back together?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My argument parser works by taking every word in your string and splitting it by the spaces. I want to put the arguments back together, but only if it is between "'s, like this

My argument list would look like this:

> ['"Hello', 'there,', 'my', 'friend!"', '"1', '2', '3"', 'gold']

And I want to put them back together:

> ['"Hello there, my friend!"', '"1 2 3"', 'gold']

But I can have multiple strings, and store each one of these full strings in an array, let's call it `fullStrings`.

I also want to make it so one-worded, no-quote arguments will also be included.

Comment: You could try `.join('').split('"')` and then add back the double quotes to each string using `.map()`. Read about [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many, many hours of head scratching I came up with this abombination of a regex:

```js
function parseArgs(input) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(/"((?:[^"]|"\S*")*)"(?=\s)|(?<=^|\s)([^"\s]+)(?=$|\s)/g)).map(a => a[2] ?? a[1]);
}


console.log(parseArgs(`"Hello there, my friend!" "1 2 3" gold`))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! It works the way I want it to ;)

Answer (score 2):

Kind of simple solution in declarative way

Using: [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) [String#replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const result = ['"Hello', 'there', ',', 'my', 'friend!"', '"1', '2', '3"']
  .join(' ')                  // '"Hello there , my friend!" "1 2 3"'
  .replaceAll(' ,', ',')      // '"Hello there, my friend!" "1 2 3"'
  .replaceAll('" "', '"" ""') // '"Hello there, my friend!"" ""1 2 3"'
  .split('" "');              //['"Hello there, my friend!"', '"1 2 3"']
  

result.map((o) => console.log(o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works just the way I wanted it do. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this but it does include a space after the there i.e. `there ,` which may not be suitable for you?

output = ['"Hello there , my friend!"', '"1 2 3"']

```js
const words = ['"Hello', 'there', ',', 'my', 'friend!"', '"1', '2', '3"']
let fullString = '';

words.forEach((word, index) => {
  fullString += (index > 0)? ` ${word}`:`${word}`; //create sentence
});

// split on '"' and filter out empty values
const fullStrings = fullString.split('"').filter(Boolean).map((r)=>{
  let result = (r != ' ')? `"${r}"`: null;
  return result;
}).filter(Boolean); //remove null

console.log(fullStrings);
```